# inherit from a base class

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Let say I have this class :

```
class foo
{
    public foo(Guid guid)
    {
        //some code here
    }

    public foo(Guid guid, bool myBool)
    {
        //some other code here
    }

    //Here I have a bunch of method/properties

    public void GenX(bool french, int width)
    {
        //my method implementation
    }
}
```

and I have another class that does basically all the same than `foo` except the implementation of this method `public GenX(bool french, int width)` and the construtor must be different from `foo`'s implementation.

If I implement `bar` this way the compiler complain : `'foo' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments`

```
class bar : foo
{
    public bar(Guid guid, bool myBool)
    {
        //some code here
    }

    new public void GenX(bool french, int width)
    {
        //my new method implementation
    }

    //I will be using the implementation of `foo` for the rest of the methods/properties
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct way to do this kind of thing?

If this isn't clear enought I apologies and I will try to make it clearer

Comment: Are You sure it's whole code? Shouldn't it be: class bar : foo Please show us line which is causing this error

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I edited the question

Comment: Regarding your `bar.GenX` method, did you intend to shadow the base's method, or did you mean to override it?

Comment: @valverij for now let say this is the desired behaviour. I will have to test in my context to see if I should simply override

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to make sure that the base constructor is called.

You can do that like this:

```
class bar : foo
{
    public bar(Guid g, bool b) : base (g)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Since you haven't specified this in your code, the compiler will try to call the default constructor by default/implicitly.   However, since your base class doesn't have a default constructor (because you've specified another constructor, without specifying the default constructor), it cannot call it.
Hence, you'll have to tell the compiler what constructor of the base-class it should use.

In the case that the constructor in your inherited class does something completely different then the constructor in your base-class, and you do not whish to reuse the constructor of your base class, you can do this:

```
class foo
{
   protected foo() 
   { 
      // default constructor which is protected, so not useable from the 'outside' 
   }

   public foo( Guid g ) 
   {}

   public foo( Guid g, bool b) : this(g) 
   {}

   public virtual void GenX() {}
}

class bar : foo
{
   public bar( Guid g, bool b) : base()
   {}

   public override void GenX() {}
}
```

Comment: I need to do this even if the code in the base constructor doesn't have any value for `bar` ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean ?

Comment: Also, you may want to declare foo.GenX as virtual, and use the override keyword instead of the new keyword for far.GenX. This will make GenX polymorphic.

Comment: The code in `foo` constructor isn't applicable at `bar`'s level. Basically bar have a different constructor and need a different implementation of `GenX`

Comment: Another question: why does bar inherit from foo ?

Comment: This is a good question :) basically `foo` is doing generating a repport (`GenX()`) from an existing structure in the database. `bar` is creating every thing from different informations and need to create all the structure in memory. I hope this is clear enought... :O

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
class foo
{
    public foo(Guid guid)
    {
        //some code here
    }

    public foo(Guid guid, bool myBool,bool fooclass = true)
    {

        if (fooclass)
        {
            //some other code here
        }

    }

    //Here I have a bunch of method/properties

    public void GenX(bool french, int width)
    {
        //my method implementation
    }
}

class bar : foo
{
    public bar(Guid guid, bool myBool,bool barclass = true) : base(guid,myBool,false)
    {
        //some code here
    }

    new public void GenX(bool french, int width)
    {
        //my new method implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't look to be a good way to deal with this. Also i'm in c#3.0 so I can't use default parameter (this wasn't specified in the the question... but how ever was kind of irrevelant to the question)